# How do I serialize an ArrayList of objects and save it to a file (in android)?

Tags: java, android, serialization, arraylist, save

This is probably really simple, but after having read a number of guides, I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. The following is supposed to serialize and save a list of objects contained in an ArrayList. It works, *except* all instance variables contained in the objects in the ArrayList, are lost.

Edit: can someone tell me if this part of the code is correct?

```
try {
        FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput ( FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream ( fos );
        oos.writeObject ( arrayList );
        oos.close ();
    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace ();
    }
```

Comment: I simplified the question to just basically checking if this particular part of the code is correct.

Comment: all the same you have to avoid duplicate post

Answer (score 2):

First you should check the Logcat output whether writing, or reading fails.

You are using oos.writeObject(arrayList);
Make sure that the items of arrayList are **implementing the Serializable interface**, else the writing will fail.
For example:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable { }
...
ArrayList<MyClass> arrayList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
/*add items*/
oos.writeObject(arrayList);//it will not throw Exception, because MyClass implements Serializable
```

and reading with `(ArrayList<MyClass>) ois.readObject();` but you know that.

Comment: As far as I can tell, neither of them give me an error message. I'm fairly confident that reading works, because while the program currently returns "null" for any variable, the same variable is returned correctly if it's initialized in the class itself.